# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'length'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error

I'm getting this error within the equipmentExercises block while fetching the data from the API. I have already checked the datatype which is an array.
And equipmentExercises.length is showing an undefined datatype.

```
const SimilarExercises = ({ targetMuscleExercises, equipmentExercises }) => {
    console.log(equipmentExercises);
    return (
        <Box sx={{ mt: { lg: '100px', xs: '0px' } }}>
            <Typography
                sx={{ fontSize: { lg: '44px', xs: '25px' }, ml: '20px' }}
                fontWeight={700}
                color="#000"
                mb="33px"
            >
                Similar <span style={{ color: '#FF2625', textTransform: 'capitalize' }}>Target Muscle</span> exercises
            </Typography>
            <Stack direction="row" sx={{ p: 2, position: 'relative' }}>
                {targetMuscleExercises.length !== 0 ? <HorizontalScrollbar data={targetMuscleExercises} /> : <Loader />}
            </Stack>

            <Typography
                sx={{ fontSize: { lg: '44px', xs: '25px' }, ml: '20px', mt: { lg: '100px', xs: '60px' } }}
                fontWeight={700}
                color="#000"
                mb="33px"
            >
                Similar <span style={{ color: '#FF2625', textTransform: 'capitalize' }}>Equipment</span> exercises
            </Typography>
            <Stack direction="row" sx={{ p: 2, position: 'relative' }}>
                **{equipmentExercises.length !== 0 ? <HorizontalScrollbar data={equipmentExercises} /> : <Loader />}**
            </Stack>
        </Box>
    );
};
```

Comment: Maybe on the initial load, it is set as null and later populated via the API call. Try to set the initial array value as `[]` instead of null

Comment: Already did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `equipmentExercises` and `targetMuscleExercises` might be null at first place.

You can fix this by adding a check like this: `equipmentExercises?.length !== 0`  or `equipmentExercises && equipmentExercises.length !== 0`

Comment: I'm getting this error with only `equipmentExercises`. I have already applied your prescribed check but it is still showing the error.

Comment: I think then error might be in your `HorizontalScrollbar` component where you are passing this array.

Comment: Use equipmentExercisesData and targetMuscleExercisesData instead of simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could be passing in a string of an array, instead of an array. Are you able to validate with `typeof`?

[Array and String console.log output look very similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFxU5.png)